# aws ecs update-service not working desired-count =1 but running =0 after jenkins build

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, terraform, amazon-ecs

### What is working fine

I have successfully created a AWS ECS cluster using terraform script

with following parameters

```
max_instance_size = 2
min_instance_size = 1
desired_capacity  = 1

"maximumPercent": 100,
"minimumHealthyPercent": 0
```

Everything is working fine when I am creating this Cluster . My application is up and running and accessible through Load Balancer.

### What is giving problem

Now i have a Jenkins Job to do following steps

1. Checkout
2. Build Application
3. Create Docker Image
4. Push Docker image into Hub
5. Deploy the image through Task Definition update.

Here is the Jenkins snippet

```
stage("Deploy") {

sh  "sed -e  's;%BUILD_TAG%;${BUILD_NUMBER};g' accountupdateecs-task-defination.json > accountupdateecs-task-defination-${BUILD_NUMBER}.json"

def currTaskDef = sh (returnStdout: true,script:  "aws ecs describe-task-definition  --task-definition ${taskFamily}| egrep 'revision'| tr ',' ' '| awk '{print \$2}'").trim()  

def currentTask = sh (returnStdout: true,script:  "aws ecs list-tasks  --cluster ${clusterName} --family ${taskFamily} --output text | egrep 'TASKARNS' | awk '{print \$2}' ").trim()

if(currTaskDef) {sh  "aws ecs update-service  --cluster ${clusterName} --service ${serviceName} --task-definition ${taskFamily}:${currTaskDef} --desired-count 0 "}

if (currentTask) {sh "aws ecs stop-task --cluster ${clusterName} --task ${currentTask}"}

sh  "aws ecs register-task-definition  --family ${taskFamily} --cli-input-json ${taskDefile}"

def taskRevision = sh (returnStdout: true, script:  "aws ecs describe-task-definition  --task-definition ${taskFamily} | egrep 'revision' | tr ',' ' ' | awk '{print \$2}'").trim()

sh  "aws ecs update-service  --force-new-deployment --cluster ${clusterName} --service ${serviceName} --task-definition ${taskFamily}:${taskRevision} --desired-count 1" 

}
```

#### Issue

After successfully execution of job my always i can see in cluster

```
desired-count = 1
running       = 0
```

and application is not available.

Here is the success log of jenkins

```
+ aws ecs update-service --force-new-deployment --cluster FinanceManagerCluster --service financemanager-ecs-service --task-definition accountupdateapp:20 --desired-count 1
{
    "service": {
        "serviceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:3432423423423:service/financemanager-ecs-service",
        "serviceName": "financemanager-ecs-service",
        "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:3432423423423:cluster/FinanceManagerCluster",
        "loadBalancers": [
            {
                "targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:3432423423423:targetgroup/ecs-target-group/ed44ae00d0de463d",
                "containerName": "accountupdateapp",
                "containerPort": 8181
            }
        ],
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "desiredCount": 1,
        "runningCount": 0,
        "pendingCount": 0,
        "launchType": "EC2",
        "taskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:3432423423423:task-definition/accountupdateapp:20",
        "deploymentConfiguration": {
            "maximumPercent": 100,
            "minimumHealthyPercent": 0
        },
        "deployments": [
            {
                "id": "ecs-svc/9223370480222949120",
                "status": "PRIMARY",
                "taskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:3432423423423:task-definition/accountupdateapp:20",
                "desiredCount": 1,
                "pendingCount": 0,
                "runningCount": 0,
                "createdAt": 1556631826.687,
                "updatedAt": 1556631826.687,
                "launchType": "EC2"
            },
            {
                "id": "ecs-svc/9223370480223135598",
                "status": "ACTIVE",
                "taskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:3432423423423:task-definition/accountupdateapp:19",
                "desiredCount": 0,
                "pendingCount": 0,
                "runningCount": 0,
                "createdAt": 1556631640.195,
                "updatedAt": 1556631823.692,
                "launchType": "EC2"
            }
        ],
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::3432423423423:role/ecs-service-role",
        "events": [
            {
                "id": "967c99cc-5de0-469f-8cdd-adadadad",
                "createdAt": 1556631824.549,
                "message": "(service financemanager-ecs-service) has begun draining connections on 1 tasks."
            },
            {
                "id": "c4d99570-408a-4ab7-9790-adadadad",
                "createdAt": 1556631824.543,
                "message": "(service financemanager-ecs-service) deregistered 1 targets in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:3432423423423:targetgroup/ecs-target-group/ed44ae00d0de463d)"
            },
            {
                "id": "bcafa237-598f-4c1d-97e9-adadadad",
                "createdAt": 1556631679.467,
                "message": "(service financemanager-ecs-service) has reached a steady state."
            },
            {
                "id": "51437232-ed5f-4dbb-b09f-adadadad",
                "createdAt": 1556631658.185,
                "message": "(service financemanager-ecs-service) registered 1 targets in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:3432423423423:targetgroup/ecs-target-group/ed44ae00d0de463d)"
            },
            {
                "id": "c42ee5c9-db5b-473a-b3ca-adadadad",
                "createdAt": 1556631645.944,
                "message": "(service financemanager-ecs-service) has started 1 tasks: (task fc04530a-479d-4385-9856-adadadad)."
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": 1556631640.195,
        "placementConstraints": [],
        "placementStrategy": [],
        "healthCheckGracePeriodSeconds": 0
    }
```

Need some help to understand and resolve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like it's just waiting for the new task definition to start. Either you just need to wait or the task is never going to start because it happens to be broken for whatever reason. Can you see stopped tasks for the service? Also is there a reason why you're not running with the default deploy options so it will rolling deploy the new version?

Comment: Thanks .. could you please point me where can i change the deploy option .

Comment: Thanks .. it has been resolved .. It was my mistake with image tag name .. i have changed it and now it is deploying in cluster ..